# Formatting numbers in Microsoft Word 2007 mailmerge

Tags: ms-word, number-formatting, mailmerge

I'm using Mailmerge in MS Word 2007 to generate a letter that contains a number of records for each addressee.
The codes I have is:

```
{MERGEFIELD Date}    {MERGEFIELD Description}    {MERGEFIELD Amount \# $,0.00}
```

I have a tab set at 1.5" Left Alignment for the Description
and a tab set at 4.5" Decimal Alignment for the Amount

the last column looks like

- $300.00
- $45.00
- $250.00

instead of

- $ 300.00
- $..   45.00
- $ 250.00

How do I correct it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to do something like this:
Set a Left tab for the dollar sign
Set a Decimal tab for the number, allowing enough space for the largest possible number in your data
Modify the numeric formatting switch in your Amount field so that the field looks like this:

```
{MERGEFIELD Amount \\#"$,[tab]0.00"}
```

but where you insert a normal tab character instead of [tab].